# Strapi marketplace not open

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

[image]

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
at NpmPackageCard (Admin_marketplace.7a793478.chunk.js:527:30)

I updated to Strapi 4.9.0 and in this version do not open marketplace, when I rolback to 4.8.2 version, yet not open and the same error persist.

I was expecting the marketplace open and I could install plugins

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a confirmed bug that they're working on.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/16261